# Using ILIKE with parameters in Python with pd.read_sql and psycopg2

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

This query runs without problem in SQL (PostgreSQL database):

```
SELECT 

number_column
                
FROM 

number_table

WHERE 

number_column ILIKE ANY (array[     '%57244048699%',
                                    '%150310003808%',
                                    '%290030480768%',
                                    '%290070002130%',
                                    '%290100059345%',]
```

I am trying to translate this into Python as follows:

```py
numbers = ['%57244048699%',
           '%150310003808%',
           '%290030480768%',
           '%290070002130%',
           '%290100059345%',]

sql_query = """

          SELECT 

number_column
                
FROM 

number_table

WHERE 

number_column ILIKE ANY (array[%(numbers)s]

            """
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine, params = {'numbers':tuple(numbers)})
```

However, I am getting the following error thrown:

```
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: character varying ~~* record
LINE 19:                 where number ilike any (array[('%...
                                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the above to make the query run in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the `psycopg2` docs [List adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list) a list is adapted to an array. So you are over complicating things.

Try :

`number_column ILIKE ANY (%(numbers)s)`

and the argument:

`{'numbers': numbers}`

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import psycopg2

#establishing the connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database="mydb", user='postgres', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432'
)

#Setting auto commit false
conn.autocommit = True

#Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
cursor = conn.cursor()
numbers = ['%57244048699%',
               '%150310003808%',
               '%290030480768%',
               '%290070002130%',
               '%290100059345%',]
number_tuple=tuple(numbers)
sql_query = "SELECT number_column           
FROM 
number_table
WHERE 
number_column ILIKE ANY {}".format(number_tuple)
    
cursor.execute(sql_query )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to get this to work using the `pd.read_sql` method? I am not familiar with the `cursor.execute` function.

Comment: @R.W. I have aded the cursor code!!

Comment: Please in your example show proper parameter passing as described here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Otherwise you are opening yourself and others to SQL injection.